# How do I align multiple divs contained within a footer div using CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, alignment

How do I align the code below using CSS?  I formerly had all the alignment within my HTML tags but I am trying to see how this would be done using CSS.

Here is the layout that I envision:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kZBfc.png

Here is a jsfiddle with HTML and CSS: http://jsfiddle.net/4yX4A/

As you can see, I would like the logo centered exactly within the footer element.  I would like the address element to be aligned to the top/left and I would the links to be aligned top/right.  The social media links/images would be aligned right/bottom.

CSS alignment is much more confusing than HTML in my opinion but I have heard that if you get the hang of it it makes management of the site much easier.

Anybody have any tips tricks?  Am I even doing my HTML correctly?

TIA

```
<div id="footer">

    <div id="contact_links">
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="contact"><span>Web Director</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="contact"><span>Office</span></a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>

    <div id="social">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="http://www.facebook.com/mypagejohndoe">
                    <img width="27" height="27" alt="Facebook" src="img/icon_facebook.png">
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="logo-img">
        <img src="images/logo.png" alt="Company" title="Logo" height="150px" width="150px"     />
    </div>

    <div id="address">
        <span class="title">Office</span>
        <br>
        <span class="info">PO Box 0000</span>
        <br>
        <span class="info">Someplace, XX  00000</span>
        <br>
        <span class="info">(555) 555-5555</span>
        <br>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: You haven't shown us any of your CSS, what do you have so far?

Comment: put your html and css into http://jsfiddle.net/ and see what you get. then link to it in your question

Comment: Please provide your current CSS and also a jsfiddle as suggested above. A PNG is of no use

Comment: I have added a jsfiddle with the CSS I currently have coded.  I apologize for the omission.

Answer (score 0):

Use float: left.
Set the width and left margin of your divs.

Alternatively, you could make something work with display: inline-block;

```
#footer div {
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
    margin-left: 1em;
}
#footer div:first-child {
    margin-left: 0;
}
```

Comment: I've tried this and it has gotten me nowhere.  I apologize, as I am new to CSS as I noted.  I've added the CSS I am currently using.  Is there anything in there that is throwing off my coding?  http://jsfiddle.net/4yX4A/

Comment: Throw that additional css into your fiddle and hit run.